# R: Color data table cell if value contains a certain string

Tags: r, dplyr, dt

I'm trying to create a fantasy football board that tracks average draft position (ADP) of each NFL player for the upcoming 2019 season. I'm using a call to an API at https://fantasyfootballcalculator.com/. I would like to build something in a Shiny app that looks similar to the draft board at their site, but one I can customize on my end:

[image]

It doesn't have to look nearly as pretty as this, but I want the cells colored coded by position; as you can see, the background colors show which position each player plays: blue for RB, green for WR, red for QB, and so on.

I realize using DT in R, I can color cells if they're a numerical value, **but could I possibly color cells if they contain certain string values like "- RB" or "- WR"**? I currently have the following code built into a DT table that displays the player and position in the following format: "Player Name - Position".

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

half_ppr_players = RJSONIO::fromJSON(getURL("https://fantasyfootballcalculator.com/api/v1/adp/half-ppr?teams=12&year=2019"))

half_ppr_df = do.call(rbind.data.frame, half_ppr_players$players)

rownames(half_ppr_df) <- seq(length=nrow(half_ppr_df))

keepers = c()

half_ppr_df = half_ppr_df %>%
  filter(!(name %in% keepers)) 

half_ppr_df = half_ppr_df %>%
  mutate(name = as.character(name),
         adp_rank = 1:nrow(half_ppr_df),
         rd = floor(adp_rank/12),
         pick = ifelse(adp_rank %% 12 == 0, 12, adp_rank %% 12),
         rd = ifelse(pick == 12, rd, rd + 1))

m = matrix(nrow = 17, ncol = 12)
for (row in 1:17) {
  for (col in 1:12) {
    this_row = half_ppr_df[half_ppr_df$rd == row & half_ppr_df$pick == col,]
    if(row %% 2 == 0) {
      m[row, 12-col+1] = paste(this_row$name, '-', this_row$position)
    } else {
      m[row, col] = paste(this_row$name, '-', this_row$position)
    }
  }
}

draftboard = as.data.frame(m)
colnames(draftboard) = paste("Pick", seq(1, ncol(m), 1))
rownames(draftboard) = paste("Rd", seq(1, nrow(m), 1))
DT::datatable(draftboard)
```

I'm currently using DT because that's what I'm used to wielding in Shiny apps, but I'm open to other options. I also understand that I may have to build a custom Javascript function. Any ideas?

Comment: As a side, if you aren't afraid of not-yet-released packages, [`rstudio/gt`](https://github.com/rstudio/gt) supports per-cell colors. I'm not a dev on it, I just know that it can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("John - RB", "Max - WR"),
  V2 = c("Bill - WR", "David - RB")
)

js <- "(/- WR/).test(value) ? 'red' : (/- RB/).test(value) ? 'yellow' : ''"

datatable(dat) %>% 
  formatStyle(1:ncol(dat), backgroundColor = JS(js))
```

[image]